# Boxy this submit does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, boxy

I have several forms in my code, and I want to assign a Confirmation Box to show before it is submitted.

Hence, I use Boxy Jquery, however after the user confirms, `$(this).submit()` does not work. Is this because there are more than 1 form?

Here is my JS:

```
$("form").submit(function(ev) {
        Boxy.confirm("Are you sure?", function() { $(this).submit(); }, {title: 'Confirm'});
        return false;

});
```

Comment: try using  $('#formId').submit(); instead of  $(this).submit(); here formId is the id to your form.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("form").submit(function(ev) {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        Boxy.confirm("Are you sure?", function() { $this.submit(); }, {title: 'Confirm'});
        return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a submit button that triggers the form submit, you can do something like this:

```
$(".button").click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    Boxy.confirm("Are you sure?", function() { $('form').submit(); }, {title: 'Confirm'});
});
```